# Hyphenated site answers, can they be pasted on SO if linked?

Tags: discussion, copyright, experts-exchange

I asked a question on SO. I got answered by a link to the h-site. I went there and the answer is actually somewhat good, an approach not typically used.

What's the policy on pasting that code here with attribution? Do we have any?

I skimmed through the member agreement and it seems to me that there is no express prohibition.

Answer (score 4):

If you've got your problem solved elsewhere, copy the code/answer here, link to the source, and then in two days, mark it as the answer. We're building a canonical site of programming answers.

Bing, bang, boom.